# Windows 8 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-8, ubuntu-12.04

I would like to run Windows 8 within a virtual machine under Ubuntu.

I tried using a virtual machine and VMware but could not get it to work.

If anyone who has tried using Windows 8 on virtual machine in Ubuntu 12.04 could suggest where I might have gone wrong.

Comment: You might want to add any errors you encountered, so that people can identify the problem.

Comment: got my mistake this link was helpful http://www.techulator.com/resources/5081-install-windows-vmware-workstation.aspx

Comment: should I mention it as my answer?

Comment: If the link solved your problem, you can and should answer your own question. But please don't *just* post the link. Include a quick summary of the required steps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please sow your error during installation.
I had one  "Your PC needs to be repaired".
And I found a solution, might work for you.
Close the Windows 8 window, select your virtual machine in VirtualBox, click Settings > System > Processor and check the 'Enable PAE/NX' box. Click OK, restart your virtual machine and this time it should launch properly.